# Add instance to a Volume in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created an instance m2.2xlarge which works fine.
I am trying to add this instance to a volume. Volume created fine and see in list of volumes.
The status of this volume shows up as "available".
In the "Action" - Attach volume and then select instance from drop down list- this above instance does not show up. I have another micro instance which shows up fine in the drop down list.

Why is the m2 large instance not showing up in the drop down list (for available instances)?
Is this the way to add a volume to a new instance?

Comment: Is the volume in the same availability zone as your instance?

Comment: they are in same zone

Comment: The only reason I can think of as to why a volume does not show up to a given instance is that it is not in the same zone. Keep in mind region and zone are two different things. In the case of EBS volumes, they need to be in the same zone.

Comment: Try doing it with the command line tool and see what sort of error message you get when you try to attach.

Comment: @user2671313: you're probably thinking of regions - it might be in the same region but different AZ. Please double-check.